# How to import a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I was asked to create a virtual machine using vmware but I only received two files:

- one with extension .vmsd
- another one with extension .disk1

I am not seeing any option how to import such files and have the VM running. Please, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can just drag the files into the VMWare window. I believe you need a `.vmx` file though. All you have right now is a snapshot (`vmsd`), and a disk, and I'm pretty sure you need the config file as well.

Comment: Also, the import option is `File->Scan for Virtual Machines`, then select the containing  directory.

Comment: I realized they did not send me all files needed. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[Vmware Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IgmE.png)

1. Click on **Open a virtual machine**
2. Open the location of the folder containing VMware files
3. Click on the config file that will be visible most likely a *.vmx[File to be opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMFsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

VMs can be created using two ways.

1. You can use the OS images provided by the VMware software. i.e., The list of OS available in the dropdown. This is a regular process.
2. The other way is to use your custom Image file (.iso file). This should be done while creating the VM itself but not after creation. Also your ISO file has to be pass the pre-checks done by the software.

The .vmsd & .disk1 files which you mentioned are for maintaining the metadata & files. You can attack them during the creation of VM in the Attach external disks section if I'm not wrong.